# how to copy rows and columns to another worksheets on another workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

i have several workbooks which get copy from one master workbook. what i want to do is when i enter data into the master workbook, i want to copy it into another workbook based on product type which i get fromn Combobox1.Value. to be more clear, which workbooks i want to copy the data depends on the ComboBox1.value. ie if the ComboBox1.value equals to "Penofix" then i want to copy the data into the  workbook "Penofix.xlsm". i have finish coding on master input on how to enter data into particular row based on some condition but facing problem to copy the data into another workbooks.

```
Private Sub CmdEnter_Click()

Dim CountRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim prod as string
Dim j As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Count1 as Long


'CountRow is number of row in master workbook
CountRow = Worksheets("Input").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'assign variable prod with combobox1 value
prod = ComboBox1.Value
'i=32 because my row start at 32
For i = 32 To countRow + 31

While ComboBox1.Value = Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 2).Value
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Insert shift = xlDown

    With Worksheets("Input")
    'insert data into master workbook
    .Range("B" & i) = ComboBox1.Text
    .Range("C" & i) = TextBox1.Text
    .Range("D" & i) = TextBox2.Text
    .Range("E" & i) = TextBox3.Text
    .Range("F" & i) = TextBox4.Text
    .Range("G" & i) = TextBox5.Text
    .Range("H" & i) = ComboBox2.Text
    .Range("I" & i) = TextBox6.Text
    .Range("J" & i) = TextBox7.Text
    .Range("K" & i) = TextBox8.Text

    End With
   'activate other workbook to copy data,if prod = Penofix,the workbook will be "Penofix.xlsm"
   workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").Activate
   'count the number of row in workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").
   ' i specified  cell (31,3) to calculate the number of row used
   Count1  = Workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(31,3).Value
   Count1  = Count1  + 31

   'copy data into workbooks(prod & ".xlsm")
   'THIS IS THE LINE WHICH ERROR
    Workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range(Cells(Count1,  2), Cells(Count1 , 11)).Value = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 11)).Value   

    If MsgBox("One record written to Input. Do you want to continue entering data?", vbYesNo)=     vbYes Then
     ComboBox1.Text = ""
     TextBox1.Text = ""
     TextBox2.Text = ""
     TextBox3.Text = ""
     TextBox4.Text = ""
     TextBox5.Text = ""
     ComboBox2.Text = ""
     TextBox6.Text = ""
     TextBox7.Text = ""
     TextBox8.Text = ""

        Else
            Unload Me
    End If

    Exit Sub
 Wend
Next
End Sub
```

i've try to replace

```
 Workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range(Cells(Count1,  2), Cells(Count1 , 11)).Value = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 11)).Value
```

with this

```
  Workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Cells(Count1, 2).Value = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 2).Value
```

and yeah its work but it just for one singe cell only. so i think the error is on the syntax :

```
  Range(Cells(Count1,2), Cells(Count1,11))
```

but i dont know how to make it to copy the entire row

Comment: I would rate this type of Excel-VBA questions as most frequenty asked category here.. You only say you have *a problem copying data to another sheet..*, WHAT'S THE EXACT PROBLEM? `1.` ERROR? `2.` SIMPLY NOT SURE ABOUT CODE SNIPPET?

Comment: @bonCodigo i've update the question and the coding i've done. but still get error. or u still not clear what is my question?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range(cells(i,B).cells(i,K)).Value = _
    Workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(CountRow, B). Cells(CountRow, K)).Value
```

This code will update the master workbook, I doubt you want to this. Also there is a syntax error with `.).`  and then some.

I think this is what you need:

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = Workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Input")

sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(CountRow, 2), sht1.Cells(CountRow, 11)).Value = _
    sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(i, 2), sht2.Cells(i, 11)).Value
```

---

**Imroved code:** Using `resize(<row>, <column>)`

```
Workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(CountRow, 2).resize(, 11).Value = _
    Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 2).resize(, 11).Value
```

**For some added info**, the `Cells(<Row>, <Column>)` will only take integers in for either `<Row>` and `<Column>`. Hence the column `B` is represented as `2`.

Comment: yeah my mistake.  i've tried your answer but still getting error. i try to use this Workbooks(prod & ".xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Cells(Count1, 2).Value = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 2).Value and yeah it can copy from master workbook to another workbook but it just for one cell only. dont you think the error is on Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 11))

Comment: And if you removed `.value`?

Comment: yes the wb is open. removing .value still get error. like i said when i replaced Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 11)) with cells(i,2) it copy the data but only for one single cell. that's why i think the error is on the Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 11)) syntax

Comment: cells needs to be referenced from a sheet e.g. `wb.sht.cells(1,2)`